# Cross-database chaining in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

While doing Audits found the Cross database chaining enabled for the system databases. When I run the alter database query to disable, it says that the value cannot be set.

A few questions :

1. Why the system databases do not allow us to disable this control?
2. What purpose does this serve?

Comment: It's the default state since SQL 2000. You cannot turn OFF cross-db chains for master, temp, msdb, and you cannot turn ON for model.

Comment: What risk are you trying to mitigate? Cross-database chaining for system databases would be a concern only if non-sysadmin role members can create user-defined objects in those databases. You have larger concerns if that is the case.

Comment: Thanks @Marian. I am aware of that but wanted to know why is that so.

Comment: @DanGuzman : In current environment we don't have users with permissions to create objects in system dbs. However, I had a scenario where a user loaded huge tables in msdb once as he had permissions. My current requirement is to improve the audit score which for some reason is unaware that sys dbs can't have this disabled. Have already informed to exclude these but was jus curious about it.

Comment: The problem with a user loading a huge table into msdb isn't due to database chaining, it's "once as he had permissions". A DBA responsible for security must understand the implications of adding users to system databases.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes I know that was for permission. Understood the hard way as I am still learning from mistakes. Thank you. Still searching for an explanation on why it is enabled, what purpose that serves.

Comment: I removed my answer. For making possible system sp calls guest enabled is sufficient. So my guess was wrong